# Angular2 http observables - how to work with undefined type

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am migrating some code from Angular1 to Angular2 and having a few issues.  I can open a json response, populate a template, and access data from template ng functions but have not been able to access the data directly from the component class.  From what I have read and the error messages seen Angular2 http / observable does not seem to return a pure json object, so I suspect I need to remap it, but not sure how.  I believe it should also be possible to drop back to promises using onPromise but have not managed to get that working.  I have spent a lot of time googling for solutions, and have tried to implement most of them, but no luck.  If anyone can advise on how to remap the response to a usable format or directly access data in the response it would be greatly appreciated.

Example http call from the service :-

```ts
getExam() {
    return this._http.get('/json/exam.json')
      .map(data => data.json());
  }
```

Example subscribe :-

```ts
  ngOnInit() {
      this._examsService.getExam()
        .subscribe(response => this.exam = response);
    console.log(this.exam.length);  //this fails
  }
```

Example console log error :-

```ts
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in [null]
```

Example data structure (very simplified for testing) :-

```ts
{"title":"My Practice Exam",
  "questions":[
    {"question":"1+1 = ",
      "answers":[
        {"answer":"2","correct":"Y","selected":"N","iscorrect":""},
        {"answer":"5","correct":"N","selected":"N","iscorrect":""}]},
    {"question":"2+2 = ",
      "answers":[
        {"answer":"4","correct":"Y","selected":"N","iscorrect":""},
        {"answer":"7","correct":"N","selected":"N","iscorrect":""}]},
    {"question":"3+3 = ",
      "answers":[
        {"answer":"6","correct":"Y","selected":"N","iscorrect":""},
        {"answer":"8","correct":"N","selected":"N","iscorrect":""}]}]}
```

In Angular1 I was able to directly access data from functions - e.g as follows, and would like to do similar in Angular2

```ts
if ($scope.myExams[0].questions[q].answers[a].correct == 'y') ...
```

Comment: Seems that my console.log debug did not work from ngOnInit but I am able to access the full JSOn structure from a function :-    getTitle() {
    console.log(this.exam.questions[1].answers[1].correct);
  }

Answer (score 4):

With this code

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this._examsService.getExam()
    .subscribe(response => this.exam = response);
  console.log(this.exam.length);  //this fails
}
```

the first line sends the request `this._examsService.getExam()`  `.subscribe(...)` and registers interest in the response, then `console.log(this.exam.length)` is executed, but at this time `respone => this.exam = response` hasn't been execute yet, because `getExam()` is not yet done connecting to the server and receiving the response.

You need to stay in the chain of events to work with the data that is returned eventually, like:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this._examsService.getExam()
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.exam = response;
      console.log(this.exam.length);  //this shoudn't fail anymore
    });
}
```

I don't know if this solves your problem but your question doesn't provide enough information about your requirements for a more elaborate solution.

Comment: This version of ngOnInit does complete without error, but the console.log output only shows "undefined" rather than the length of the returned object.

Comment: Then `getExam()` doesn't return a  value. Can you add the code of `getExam()` to your question?

Comment: The "undefined" issue above was because the length property only exists on JSON arrays, and is undefined on JSON objects.  I am able to return this.exam.questions.length but this.exam.length returns "undefined".  So ... basically this was due to my misunderstanding of when the length property could be used.  I very much appreciate your help, as it did force me to revisit my assumptions and test a few more combinations.

Comment: I see, thanks for the feedback. I don't know these details because I don't use TS/JS myself, I use only Dart. You could post an answer with this information.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the following case is the normal behavior:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._examsService.getExam()
    .subscribe(response => this.exam = response);
  console.log(this.exam.length);  //this fails
}
```

because you try to access the `length` property on the `exam` object that will set later and when the response will be there (in the `subscribe` method).

That said, when an error is thrown within the observable, the `map` operator isn't called. If you want to transform the error response, you can leverage the `catch` operator, as described below:

```
this._examsService.getExam()
    .subscribe(
      // Success
      response => this.exam = response,
      // Failure
      response => {
        // Do something
      });
```

and the corresponding service code:

```
getExam() {
  return this.http.get('http://...')
           .map(res = > res.json())
           .catch(res => {
             // If you want to extract the JSON error
             // message from the response
             return Observable.throw(res.json());
           });
}
```

Otherwise you can also leverage the `async` pipe to directly set the observable on the component and not do the subscribe:

```
this.exam = this._examsService.getExam();
```

and in the associated template

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="#e of exam | async">{{e.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the reply.  it does seem that ngOnInit is the wrong place to debug.  I moved the debug out to a function and was able to call it successfully from a click, so am able to access the full JSON tree.

Comment: Pleased to hear that ;-) In fact, this isn't linked to the component lifecycle (ngOnInit is a lifecycle hook) but to the observable...