# Partial observable handling in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-services

I have a component which a login form: `loginForm` which calls my api:

```
  onLogin(): void {

    let username = this.loginForm.value.username;
    let password = this.loginForm.value.password;

    this.api.login(username, password);

      .map(res => res.json())

      .subscribe(
        this._processData,
      );

  }
```

There is a service which calls an api: `loginService`.

```
login(username: string, password: string): Subscription<any> {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

    return this.http.put("https://myapi.com", JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password}), {
      headers: headers
    })

    .map(res => res.json())

    .subscribe(
      data => console.log(data),
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log("Done")
    );

}
```

What I want is the error to be handled inside the loginService. But the result back to the `onLogin` method.

I tried a variety of mapping handlers (as shown) in the onLogin but could not get it to work. Any thoughts about what I might do wrong?

Comment: First, remove the `;` before you call `.map()` in `this.api.login(username, password);` otherwise you are not calling it. Second, don't map twice , you already defined the mapper to the observable in the service. Third the second subscribe you are doing (the one in the controller) is wrong, use the same syntax you used in the service: `.subscribe(
        data => this.data = data
      );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, you define a callback within the `subscribe` method to handle error in the `login` method (the second parameter). If you want to let errors to be propagated into your `onLogin` method you need to remove this callback (and even the call of `subscribe`).

```
return this.http.put("https://myapi.com",
  JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password}), {
    headers: headers
  })
.map(res => res.json());
```

If you want to log the error and then propagate it you can leverage the `Observable.throw` method:

```
return this.http.put("https://myapi.com",
  JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password}), {
    headers: headers
  })

.map(res => res.json())

.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
  return Observable.throw(err);
});
```

In this case you need to add a callback to handle the error in the `onLogin` method:

```
onLogin(): void {
  let username = this.loginForm.value.username;
  let password = this.loginForm.value.password;

  this.api.login(username, password)
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      // Success
      this._processData(data)
    },
    (err) => {
      // Error
    }
  );
}
```

You can notice that there is a `catch` operator on `Observable` to catch error and in the case of errors, the `map` operator isn't called.

These answers could give you more details:

- [Angular2 http observables - how to work with undefined type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34925882/angular2-http-observables-how-to-work-with-undefined-type/34926033#34926033)
- [Observable Map function not running (Angular2, http)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855992/observable-map-function-not-running-angular2-http/34858066#34858066)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for your answer! On the line with `this.api.login(username, password)
  .subscribe(` I get an error saying that 'subscribe' does not exist on type `subscription<any>`

Comment: I forgot to say thay it is the subscribe in my login() function. It looks you can not subscribe in both functions or something

Comment: Yes, you're right! I did a mistake in my answer. You need to return `Observable.throw(err);`... I updated my code. It should be better now ;-)

Comment: Now I get the error `property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'`

Comment: Weird now I cleaned all my generated .js files it gives the earlier error again of `subscribe` not existing on `Subscription<any>`

Comment: Hum strange! I created a plunkr to see what I have in mind: https://plnkr.co/edit/rsJXelOYshVVBwyUJNIz?p=preview ;-)

Comment: It works. In your example above the `catch` is missing around `return Observable.throw(err.json());`. Thanks for you effort!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101403/discussion-between-osi-and-thierry-templier).

Answer (score 0):

You can define your error handler in your service, and just pass the error from component where you subscribe.

```
// component

onLogin(): void {

let username = this.loginForm.value.username;
let password = this.loginForm.value.password;

this.api
  .login(username, password)
  .subscribe(
    this._processData, // success
    this.api.onError   // error
    // if above doesn't work this should:
    // error => this.api.onError(error)
  );

}

_processData(...data) { console.log(data); }

// service

login(username: string, password: string): Subscription<any> {

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

  return this.http
    .put("https://myapi.com", JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password}), { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res.json())
}

onError(...args) { console.log(args); }
```